# A more structural proof using homomorphisms and similar tools that every ideal of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with unity , we know that if $J$ is an ideal of $M_n(R)$ then for some ideal $I$ of $R$ , $J=M_n(I)$ . The proof I know is very tedious and uses laborious manipulations using elementary matrices and all that . I was thinking , can we give a more structural proof , like using ring homomorphisms or so ? I kind of feel some hint of correspondence theorem in the result but cannot actually grasp it ... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I kind of feel some hint of correspondence theorem in the result but cannot actually grasp it

Well, there is a correspondence theorem going on, but I'm not sure that it will simplify matters.

The relationship is established through [Morita's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence), and this is just a special case. If you dig down into it, it will tell you the answer in terms of homomorphisms.

The "very tedious... laborious" version is more accessible, by comparison, and probably can be streamlined a bit to be tolerable.

Comment: Can you please present the tolerable version :) ? I really need it . And going by the link , I really did not except something so heavy ...

Comment: @SaunDev I don't have a tolerable version written out. I just mean that one can modify or come to terms with the elementary proof by changing the level of rigor. You could replace some matrix computation with something like "using elementary matrices, you can multiply to bring this entry to the upper left hand corner..." You are probably in the best position to create something that seems appropriate enough for you.